# Equivalence and implication for two identical statements

Tags: logic

I saw in a maths book the following statement:

$x>y ⇒ 2x>2y$

I think it should be written like this:

$x>y ⇔ 2x>2y$

Which of the two above statements is correct?

Comment: Both are correct but the second one is a stronger statement. Mathematicians like to use statements as week as they can.

Comment: @zoli Thanks for clarifying it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Two different claims. The second implies the first. But both are true of the natural numbers, of the real numbers, etc. So both correct.

Which of the two truths it is appropriate to assert will depend on context. And special contexts aside, in asserting the first, there need be no contextual implication that the second doesn't hold too -- only that the extra context is currently not relevant to the argument.